# 2FA Authentication in Blazor Client application over endpoint API does not get Identity.TwoFactorUserId cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly, two-factor-authentication

I am creating a web application where I implemented already everything with a working login screen, where the token is passed through a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and saved into the LocalStorage of the browser, however I faced an issue.

I tried to add two-factor authentication, following some documentations and videos, but I am facing an annoying difficulty for the past 3 weeks.

When I try to login, it sends an [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) code to the given email address as intended. - (The **email is verified** and **twofactor is enabled**.)

However, when I want to use my verification API method to verify the user, passing a username and the code, it is working in the backend (tested with my Endpoint - [Swagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_(software))), but it doesn't work through my Blazor Client application.

```
[HttpPost("verification")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithOTP([FromBody] UserVerification userVerification /* string code, string username */ )
{
    var user = await signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userVerification.Username);
    var signIn = await signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email", userVerification.Code, false, false);
    if (signIn.Succeeded)
    {
        var roles = await signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user!);
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
        };

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]!));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(configuration["JWT:ExpiryInDays"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            claims,
            expires: expiry,
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        return Ok(new UserLoginResult { Successful = true, Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
    }
    return BadRequest("Invalid code.");
}
```

In the browser I spotted that there is a cookie called **Identity.TwoFactorUserId** being created when you attempt to login and sending a code to the email, generated using the `'signInManager.UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email")'` method, and therefore after using the login endpoint in Swagger, I can use successfully the verification endpoint - as they are on the same page.

But this cookie won't be created when I try to login with my Blazor client application, therefore I am assuming that the `signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email", userVerification.Code, false, false);` is failing because of this in the verification endpoint API.

This is how it looks like when I try to login using the Enpoint in Swagger:
[Identity.TwoFactorUserId cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CgCm.png)

And this is what is missing when I try to login using my Blazor Client Application.

I tried to find where could I get this **Identity.TwoFactorUserId** token to pass manually to the Blazor Client application, but all I could find is that usually this is handled automatically.

How can I fix this problem?